# Apache POI Libraries error in Android Studio..?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apache-poi

I added 5 jar files of Apache POI so that I can save an text as .docx document but I can't run the application first I had 210 error in the grade now i have this error can someone please help me ..!? i followed this example 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mike.textword"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-3.16-beta2.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.16-beta2.jar')
compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16-beta2.jar')
compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 }
```

and now i have this error!

```
Error:Execution failed for task    ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:    org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class

Answer (score 2):

Currently Apache POI will not work on your Android Phone out of the box due to various problems that you will run into when using the libraries from Apache POI directly. Android is more strict about duplicate classes as part of the jar-files and unfortunately XmlBeans has such duplicate classes in it's jar-file.

There are two projects that try to make it possible to use Apache POI on Android:

- https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx (for Android 5) and https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX (for Android 4), both are currently still based on Apache POI 3.12
- https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (for Android 5, maintained by me), which can be more easily recompiled with newer versions of POI, e.g. it uses 3.16-beta2 currently

Answer (score 0):

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class

It means that you **are adding this class twice or more**.
**Check all you jars files** to remove it.

Comment: it is jar file how can I check it

Comment: @Eazyz you can open the jar file with a zip manager and check the classes inside for example

Comment: ok i'll try and make u know so if i found 2 location class in the jar file should i delete one of them ?